# Very High Validation while slowly increasing train

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm having trouble understanding why my validation accuracy is **very** high; around 98%. This value is after only 5 epochs through; my train accuracy is slowly increasing, as you can see from the screenshot below.

[image: 5 Epochs Through]

My data is a decently sized np array of floats, representing 9 second .WAV files.

Here is my variable explorer

[image: Variable Explorer]

Here is what my model looks like. As you can see, to decrease overfitting (which was very bad before this - 99% training acc and 26% validation) I added a 60% dropout layer; this gets me the highest validation accuracy.

```python
models = models.Sequential()
models.add(layers.Dense(20,activation = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)))
models.add(layers.Dense(4,activation = 'relu'))
models.add(layers.Dropout(.6))
models.add(layers.Dense(6,activation = 'relu'))
models.add(layers.Dense(80,activation = 'relu'))
models.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))



models.compile(optimizer ='nadam', 
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['acc'])

history = models.fit(train_data, train_labels,
                    epochs=5,
                    batch_size= 2000,
                    validation_data=(test_data, test_labels))
```

This high accuracy is even after shuffling my data, as seen below.

```python
data = np.column_stack((X,Y))
np.random.shuffle(data)

train_data = data[0:515,0:396900]
train_labels = data[0:515,396900:396904]

test_data = data[515:585,0:396900]
test_labels = data[515:585,396900:396904]
```

(Fixed data shuffling, thanks)

To be sure, I'm not complaining about this high accuracy, I simply feel like it is a result of an error or measuring the wrong value/keras computing the wrong accuracy.

Comment: @desertnaut fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure it is about shuffling the data.

Notice that in your last snippet you are not shuffling the train and test data (`X` & `Y`) only the `data` array.

To train with the data shuffled you should:

```
train_data = data[0:515,0]
train_labels = data[0:515,1]

test_data = data[515:586,0]
test_labels = data[515:586,1]
```